# How to properly extend a generic class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-class

I have created a class:

```
export class TreeClient<T extends TreeItem, K extends keyof T> {

// ...

}
```

This class has the following method:

```
public setNodeProperty(nodeId: string, property: K, setter: (_value: T[K]) => T[K]): void{
// ...
}
```

I tried to extend this class with a class that has only one generic like so:

```
export class DashboardBuilderClient<T extends TreeItem> extends TreeClient<T, keyof T> {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

but once I try to call:

```
const x = new DashboardBuilderClient<SomeType>();

x.setNodeProperty(nodeId, property, setter);
```

I get the error:

```
Argument of type '(_value: T[K]) => T[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(_value: T[keyof T]) => T[keyof T]'.
```

I understand this error that is caused by setting the second generic as `keyof T` and not something like `K extends keyof T` but is it possible to just use one generic for the wrapper class in order to avoid duplication ?

Answer (score 0):

```
type TreeItem = {
    foo: string;
}

type MyTreeItem = Event & TreeItem & {
    bar: string;
}

export class TreeClient<T extends TreeItem, K extends keyof T> {
    public setNodeProperty(nodeId: string, property: K, setter: (_value: T[K]) => T[K]): void{
    // ...
    }
}

export class DashboardBuilderClient<T extends TreeItem> extends TreeClient<T, keyof T> {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

const x = new DashboardBuilderClient<MyTreeItem>();
x.setNodeProperty('nodeId', 'bar', (_value: MyTreeItem[keyof MyTreeItem]) => 'hello');
```